# Перемещение камеры рывками Unity

Tags: unity3d

делаю игру головоломку, где есть механика перетаскивания объектов. Перемещение предметов реализовано через Configurable Joint. При нажатии левой кнопки мыши ставлю объект привязанный к телу игрока в Conected body перетаскиваемого предмета

// Параметры join'та

[image: параметры join'та]

// Иерархия объектов игрока

[image: Иерархия игрока]

// RigidBody перетаскиваемого предмета

[image: RigidBody перетаскиваемого предмета]

Расположение Hand зависит от поворота камеры игрока, скрипт поворота:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _Body;
private float _SensitivityHor = 9.0f, _RotationX = 0, _SensitivityVert = 5.0f, _MinimumVert = -45.0f, _MaximumVert = 45.0f;
void FixedUpdate()
{ 
    //Поворот камеры
    Vector3 CameraAngles = transform.localEulerAngles;
    _RotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _SensitivityVert;
    _RotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_RotationX, _MinimumVert, _MaximumVert);
    float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _SensitivityHor;
    float rotationY = CameraAngles.y + delta;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_RotationX, rotationY, 0);
    //Поворот тела персонажа
    Vector3 BodyAngles = _Body.transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 _BodyrotationY = new Vector3(BodyAngles.x, CameraAngles.y, BodyAngles.z);
    _Body.transform.eulerAngles = _BodyrotationY;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при повороте камеры объекты перемещаются рывками (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gn4HS4NIndg), причем на сцене все выглядит нормально, уже не знаю на что думать.

Comment: Куб не дёргается в статичной камере, но дергается в камере от первого лица. Дерганье, вероятно, на расстояние в один фрейм. Возможное объяснение: камера и куб обновляют своё положение не синхронно. В одном кадре куб уже сдвинут, камера - нет, в другом камера сдвинута, куб нет. Визуально это будет проявляться как дрожание куба вдоль траектории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в rigidbody перетаскиваемого предмета, после отключения интерполяции и изменения обнаружения столкновений на дискретное дергание пропало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]